# Appending JSON array to existing JSON column

Tags: mysql, json

I have some data to be inserted into a MySQL column with the JSON datatype (`blob_forms`).

The value of the fields column is populated asynchronously, and if the document has multiple pages, then I need to append the data onto the existing row.

So a same table is;

### document

document_id INT
text_data JSON
blob_forms JSON
blob_data JSON

The first chunk of data is correctly inserted and it is this data; (A sample)

```
{"fields": [
  {"key": "Date", "value": "01/01/2020"},
  {"key": "Number", "value": "xxx 2416 xx"},
  {"key": "Invoice Date", "value": "xx/xx/2020"},
  {"key": "Reg. No.", "value": "7575855"},
  {"key": "VAT", "value": "1,000.00"}
]}
```

I am using lambda (Python) to handle the database insert, using this query

```
insertString = json.dumps(newObj)
sql = "INSERT INTO `document` (`document_id`, `blob_forms`) VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `blob_forms` = %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (self.documentId, insertString, insertString))
conn.commit()
```

The problem is, I also want to do an UPDATE too, so that if `blob_forms` has a value already, it would add the new items in the `fields` array to the existing objects `fields` array.

So basically use the original data input a second, so that if it is sent again, with the same document_id it would append to any existing data in blob_forms but preserve the JSON structure.

(Please note other processes write to this table and possibly this row due to the async nature, as the data for the columns can be written in any order, but the document_id ties them all together.

My failed attempt was something like this;

```
SET @j = {"fields": [{"key": "Date", "value": "01/01/2020"},{"key": "Number", "value": "xxx 2416 xx"},{"key": "Invoice Date", "value": "xx/xx/2020"},{"key": "Reg. No.", "value": "7575855"},{"key": "VAT", "value": "1,000.00"}]}

INSERT INTO `document` (`document_id`, `blob_forms`) VALUES ('DFGHJKfghj45678', @j) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE blob_forms = JSON_INSERT(blob_forms, '$', @j)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can get the results that you want with 1 clean query in mysql. My advice would be to make the changes to the array on the client side (or wherever) and updating the entire field without delving into whether there is an existing value or not. I architect all of my api's in this way to keep the database interactions clean and fast.

Answer (score 0):

So far this looks closest;

```
SET @j = '{"fields": [{"key": "Date", "value": "01/01/2020"},{"key": "Number", "value": "xxx 2416 xx"},{"key": "Invoice Date", "value": "xx/xx/2020"},{"key": "Reg. No.", "value": "7575855"},{"key": "VAT", "value": "1,000.00"}]}';

INSERT INTO `document` (`document_id`, `blob_forms`) VALUES ('DFGHJKfghj45678', @j) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE blob_forms = JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(blob_forms, @j)
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if the blob_forms is a NULL and it does the JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE, then nothing gets saved